# SQL : insert data from one table into two tables related to each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table tSource which is a SELECT result of a cartesian product, so there is no unique ID in the set. In short lets say the table looks like the following:

```
tSource
-------
f1 | f2
-------
 H |  a
 I |  b
 J |  c
 K |  d
 K |  d
```

i need to "split" the data of tSource into tbl1 and tbl2 which are related to each other:

```
tbl1             tbl2
-------          -----------------
ID | f1          ID | tbl1_ID | f2
-------          -----------------
11 |  H          51 |      11 |  a
12 |  I          52 |      12 |  b
13 |  J          53 |      13 |  c
14 |  K          54 |      14 |  d
15 |  K          55 |      15 |  d
```

ID Columns in both destination tables are INT IDENTITY

any help would be appreciated,
thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the two insertions operations altogether in a MERGE + OUTPUT statement.

```
merge @table2 as t2
using (
    select *
    from @table
) as src
on (1 = 2)
when not matched then
    insert (f1)
    values (src.f1)
output inserted.ID, src.f2 into @table3 (f1ID, f2)
;
```

complete example:

```
declare @table table (
    f1 char(1)
    , f2 char(1)
)

insert @table
values
('H', 'a')
, ('I', 'b')
, ('J', 'c')
, ('K', 'd')


declare @table2 table (
    ID int not null identity
    , f1 char(1)
)

declare @table3 table (
    ID int not null identity
    , f1ID int not null
    , f2 char(1)
)

merge @table2 as t2
using (
    select *
    from @table
) as src
on (1 = 2)
when not matched then
    insert (f1)
    values (src.f1)
output inserted.ID, src.f2 into @table3 (f1ID, f2)
;

select *
from @table2

select *
from @table3
```

Comment: this is the most accurate example, though answer by AmitSingh was very quick and acceptable, since it did the job !
i'll start using the merge method after i get used to it, because it's something new for me!

Comment: I think I gave the best approach IMHO, but if you really feel like going the other (not guaranteed to work) way, do it. One usually know one shouldn't rely on IDENTITY ordering when inserting multiple rows.

Comment: after a heavy test i migrated to the MERGE approach. the only problem was that if the two destination tables are primary / foreign then merge fails in output into section, but i overcome it with a @temp table

Answer (score 1):

Part1-:

```
insert into tbl1(f1)  select f1 from tSource;
```

Part2-:

```
Insert into Tabl2 (tbl1_id,f2)
(
Select id,f2 from (Select Row_Number() Over(Partition by id order by id) as row,t1.f2,t2.id from t1 ,t2) a 
where row=(Select r from
( Select Row_Number() over(Order by id)as r,id  from t2) b where b.id=a.id)
)
```

here What Select Of Part 2 Return ....[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21a8b/12)

Answer (score 0):

this is not intirely correct SQL (because i don't know the types) but i think you will get the idea

```
create table tbl1(ID primary key identity, f1, f2)

insert into tbl1(f1, f2) select f1, f2 from tSource

create table tbl2(ID primary key identity, tbl1_ID not null, f2)

insert into tbl2(tbl1_ID, f2) select ID, f2 from tbl1

alter table tbl1 drop column f2

alter table tbl2 add constraint myForeignKey foreignkey(tabl1_ID) references tbl1(ID)
```

Comment: no distinct is allowed, since every row must be inserted into destination tables. tbl1 and tbl2 must have the same amount of records in the end

Comment: Then, just ignore the distinct in the first query.

Comment: @armen: i thought that f1 would be unique in tbl1, i edited my answer, hope this is what you need.

Comment: this was my first approach, but no modifications are allowed on any table !